# PHPstorm second line of tag starting to the left

Tags: intellij-idea, editor, phpstorm, indentation

Just a quick question. Whenever I have a line of code that gets too long the second line will jump all the way to the left instead of sticking below the first line according to the indentation.

```
        so instead of something like this
        what I would like
```

Example:

```
        I am getting something like this
Which I dont wan't
```

Can anybody tell me what I can do to change this behaviour. I already tried fooling around with some indentation settings but that doesn't seem to be it.

As always your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Soft Wraps section**

[image]